# Right bar button does not appear

Tags: ios, objective-c

I try to add UINavigationBar programmatically and set bar button items.
I tried:

```
self.artificialNavBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)];
    self.artificialNavBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    UIBarButtonItem *bbiDone = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Готово" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:nil action:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem *bbiTry = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:nil action:nil];
UINavigationItem *navItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] init];

    navItem.leftBarButtonItem = bbiDone;
    navItem.rightBarButtonItem = bbiTry;

    self.artificialNavBar.items = @[ navItem ];
    [self.view addSubview:self.artificialNavBar];
```

However, only left bar button appears, right one is hidden. Did i miss something?

Comment: show `artificialNavBar` declaration.

Comment: @Mr.UB property (nonatomic) UINavigationBar *artificialNavBar;

Comment: make this strong as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UINavigationItem *navItem;
```

in the .h file of this class where you have written all these and then replace your code with below code.

```
self.artificialNavBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)];
self.artificialNavBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.view addSubview:self.artificialNavBar];

UIBarButtonItem *bbiDone = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Готово" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:nil action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *bbiTry = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:nil action:nil];

self.navItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] init];
[self.navItem setLeftBarButtonItem:bbiDone animated:NO]
[self.navItem setRightBarButtonItem:bbiTry animated:NO]

[self.artificialNavBar setItems:@[self.navItem] animated:NO]
```

and make sure the navbar is nonatomic and strong.

Comment: no problem. you can use this code. just remove the iboutlet..it was a mistake. i have updated the answer

Comment: ok i try, btw, properties are strong by default, if you not specify other.